# What's the attack of opportunity for a monk

Tags: dnd-3e, monk, opportunity-attack, attack

What if a monk is allowed to do an attack of opportunity on a spellcasting enemy, is the monk only allowed to one attack, or use full attack like +10 / +5 for a level 14 monk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [SRD](http://www.zombler.org/files/srd30a/combat_basics.htm) (italics mine)

> **Making an Attack of Opportunity**
>   An attack of opportunity is *a single melee attack*, and a character can only make one per round. The character does not have to make an attack of opportunity if the character doesn't want to. The character makes the attack of opportunity at the character's normal base attack bonus.

An opportunity attack is a single attack, so you'd get a single attack at +10.
Worth noting that if you used Flurry of Blows or any other feature that decreases your to hit roll for the whole round, it still applies to this roll.

Comment: @Stef you might want to unaccept this answer and wait a pair of days before (eventually) accepting it again. When an answer gets accepted what usually happens is that no more answers get posted, because a "winner" has already been chosen.

Comment: This is mostly open-and-shut, but be careful about that last line. Flurry of Blows, yes, the penalty applies to any and all attacks that round, including subsequent AoOs. Two-Weapon Fighitng, on the other hand, explicitly applies only to that full-attack. It varies; consult the wording of the particular feature you’re using. Usually what you’re looking for are things like “one round” (until the beginning of your next turn, so including AoOs) vs. “this turn” (ends when your turn does, so doesn’t affect AoOs).